# Implement Asyncio to send multiple files through socket simultaneously

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

Just started working with asyncio Not sure how close I am Each time I run this function I dont want to disturb the previous fileloop send if it is still sending , so ultimately i can have an unlimited amount of files sending at the same time using the same function

```
 async def fileread(self):


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor,self.fileread())]
    #tasks.append(self.fileread())


    global flsize



    progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(flsize), f"Sending {fp}", unit="B", unit_scale=True,
                        unit_divisor=1024)


    with open(fp, "rb") as f:


      bytes_read = f.read(flsize)  # NEED TO SEND SMALL BYTS

      bytes_read_small = f.read(4096)



      while not flsize == 0: 



                     if not bytes_read:
                         # file transmitting is done
                         break

                     global file_sent
                     file_sent = 1

                     self.s.sendall(bytes_read)  #loop.sendall

                     progress.update(len(bytes_read))

                     file_sent = 1  

                     self.s.shutdown()

                     self.s.close()

      await asyncio.wait(tasks)


 def connect_to_server(self, *args, **kwargs):

             try:  

                    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                    loop.run_until_complete(self.fileread())
                    #asyncio.run(self.fileread())

                    # loop.close() #not sure

            except:

                    print("no op")
```

Comment: That's not how asyncio works - you can't just hide the async portion inside a sync function, keep doing other sync things, and return back to async. Your whole program must be async. Also, you don't show how `self.s` is created, but I assume it's an ordinary socket. You should be using [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) to create an async connection. Also you shouldn't use `run_in_executor` unless you know what you're doing because it uses threads under the hood and by using it you lose the benefits of async.

Comment: thanks what you say makes a lot of sense, i have re hashed the code and I will put the working version up